# Changing Text visibility according to tab and setting background color of tab

Tags: android, tabs

I have used a custom toolbar.Inside custom toolbar I do have a textView above the tabs.Now I want to set the visibility of TextView to off for the second and third tabs.This is a image of my layout

[image: screenshot]
In this image when the Ongoing tabs is selected the textfield above the tab(The ongoing survey closes on.........GMT) should be visible while for rest of the tabs the textview visibility should be gone.How can I do this?

The next problem is I have set the background of whole layout to using a background image in parent layout.But I am getting default background behind tabs.What I want is to remove the default tab background color and get the background of parent.How to do this?

This is my code for my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/innerpg_bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#42474b"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarlogo"
                android:src="@mipmap/toolbarlogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                 />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deadline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#494e51"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="The Ongoing survey closes on Dec 31,2016 at 2:00pm GMT"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my java class

```
package com.example.user.timothysurvey.activity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.user.timothysurvey.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import fragment.Ongoing;
import fragment.Result;
import fragment.Upcomming;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView deadLine;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.mipmap.ongoing,
            R.mipmap.upcoming,
            R.mipmap.results
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        deadLine= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deadline);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(0);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();


    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs, null, false);
        ((TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Ongoing");
        ((ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(tabIcons[0]);


        View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs, null, false);
        ((TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Upcomming");
        ((ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(tabIcons[1]);

        View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs, null, false);
        ((TextView) view3.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Results");
        ((ImageView) view3.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(tabIcons[2]);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view1);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(view2);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(view3);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Ongoing(), "Ongoing");
        adapter.addFrag(new Upcomming(), "Upcomming");
        adapter.addFrag(new Result(), "Result");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }





    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement OnPageChangeListener for ViewPager

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
```

Override onPageSelected methods

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.set your visiblity here with respect to tab
    if( position == 0){
        deadLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(position == 1){
        deadLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if(position == 2){
        deadLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}
```

getting default background behind tabs.add transparent background to AppBarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```